# using float inside navigationsbar

Tags: html, css

I floated the 2 links on the right side of the navigationsbar, but the inputfield went up. It should stay in the middle of the navigationbar like the button. Here is the code:

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body{
 background-color: rgb(226, 220, 220);
}

nav{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #2C2C2F;
}

nav > .nav_ul{
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 font-size: 0px;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px 0px;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_li_last_child{
 margin-right: 0px;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_li > .nav_a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 background-color: #E56E04;
 display: block;
 color: white;

 border: 1px solid #E56E04;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search > .nav_searchfield{
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #545455;
    color: white;

    border: 1px solid black;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;

 border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
 border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search > .fa-search{
 font-size: 16px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 11.5px;
 background-color: #545455;
 color: black;

 border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: none;

 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 
 border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}


/* ------------------ */

.float_right{
 float: right;
}

.float_left{
 float: left;
}

.clear_both{
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="backbone/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav_ul">
    <div class="nav_search">
     <input class="nav_searchfield" type="text" placeholder="Search ..." />
     <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
    </div>
    <li class="nav_li float_right nav_li_last_child"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Login</a></li>
    <li class="nav_li float_right"><a href="#" class="nav_a">Register</a></li>

    <div class="clear_both"></div>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

I created a div with the style `clear: both`. I placed him under the two links. But this didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons are centered using margin, use it as well with search, like this:

```
nav > .nav_ul > .nav_search{
    margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/dsr0o7dn/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! again... I thought the inputfield are centered like the button.

Comment: Hm maybe I can ask you one more question. I want that both (button & inputfield) have the same height. I tried it now long time, but its not correct. Maybe you have an idea.

Comment: The `total height` is the sum of the `height`, `padding` and `borders`. If you have all of these properties on both elemenst with the same values then you will get the same `total height`. Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/dsr0o7dn/1/. In this case the elements are `.nav_li` and `.nav_searchfield`.